# Is it necessary to create a new coin when building a parachain?

Tags: parachain

Ethereum rollups (e.g. Optimism) use ETH as their base asset for paying gas fees.

Is it possible to use DOT for paying gas fees on a parachain? Or does the parachain creator need to create their custom coin?

Answer (score 1):

[Substrate](https://docs.substrate.io/learn/welcome-to-substrate/) is a highly customizable SDK to build your own Blockchain, and one of the things you can customize for your parachain is how to pay fees.

An example of a Polkadot parachain that uses DOT to pay fees is [Asset Hub], AssetHub is one [System Parachains](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-system-chains) and it uses DOT, the native token of Polkadot, as its own currency.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that only system parachains can use DOT to pay gas fees? Also, I'm curious how the economics work with non-native-asset chains. My understanding is that a parachain needs to"crowdloan" security from $DOT holders, who are promised a continuous airdrop in the native currency of the parachain.

Comment: No any chain can do it. The airdrop is something a parachain can do but it is not a requirement. Regarding the tokenomics, I am also interested in that so would love to hear if you found something!